# Como regresar valores con JSON en un multiselect

Tags: php, javascript, json

tengo el siguiente index, que incluye un multiselect(fselect.css y fselect.js)el cual se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Registro Mantenimiento</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = device-width">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.responsive.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="multiselect/fSelect.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="multiselect/fSelect.js"></script>
<script>
  (function($) {
      $(function() {
          $('.test_3').fSelect();
      });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans&amp;subset=latin">


<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<center>
  <br/>
<div id="contenedor" style="width: 300px">
<br/><br/>
<label>DNI</label>
<input type="text" id="dni"> 

<br/><br/>
<label>NOMBRE</label>
<input type="text" id="nombre"> 

<br/><br/>
<label>APELLIDO</label>
<input type="text" id="apellido"> 

<br/><br/>

<label>CURSOS</label>
 </br>
 <select class="test_3" id="tecnologia" name="tecnologia[]" multiple="multiple" style="height:10px;">
    <option value="Algebra">Algebra</option> 
    <option value="Aritmetica">Aritmetica</option> 
    <option value="Lenguaje">Lenguaje</option> 
    <option value="Literatura">Literatura</option>
    <option value="Historia Universal">Historia Universal</option> 
    <option value="Biologia">Biologia</option>
    <option value="Quimica">Quimica</option>
    <option value="Fisica">Fisica</option>
 </select>

 </br></br>
 <button onclick="anadir();">Añadir</button>
 <button onclick="actualizar();">Modificar</button>
 <button onclick="eliminar();">Eliminar</button>
 <input type="submit" onclick="buscar();" value="buscar">
 </div>

 <div id="ventana"> 
 </div>
 </center>

</body>
</html>
```

entonces cuando guardo mi multiselect, los valores seleccionados se guardan en la base de datos "separadas por comas".
y al momento que uso mi jSON para traer valores los llamo de la siguiente manera con la funcion buscar():

```
function buscar(){

var parametros={"dni": $("#dni").val(),}

$.ajax({

        type: 'post',
        url: '../lunes-5/buscardatos.php',
        data: parametros,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(d){
            $("#nombre").val(d[0]);
            $("#apellido").val(d[1]);

            $.each(d[2].split(","), function(i,e){

                $("#tecnologia").multiselect("refresh");
            });
        }
    });
}
```

y mi buscardatos.php es el siguiente

```
<?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("archivos",$con);

  $dni=$_POST["dni"];
  $rs=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clie  WHERE dni='$dni'");

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);

  $datos_a_enviar = array($row['nombre'], 
  $row['apellido'],$row['tecnologia']);
   echo json_encode($datos_a_enviar);
  ?>
```

entonces solo me devuelve los valores de nombre y apellido, pero no del multiselect, como se ve en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como haria para que se seleccionen los valores que marque cuando guarde el registro, si los estoy almacenando delimitado por "comas"?

Comment: la forma mas simple de trabajarlo y la correcta deberia ser con 3 tablas
1. los datos de usuario 2.cursos 3. seleccion en selecion debe estas id, id_user , id_curso!
select cu.cursos from cursos  cu inner join seleccion se on cu.id == se.id_curso inner join clie on se.id_clie == clie.'${client_id}'; esto te permitira a;adir cuantos cursos deses, cuantas selecciones deses, y clientes sin limites!

Comment: mi consulta era como llamarlo en el JSON

Comment: puedes hacerlo con el `e`  $.each(d[2].split(","), function(i,e){  console.log(i,e) `i` es el indice y `e` es el valor o tambien hacerlo asi: var multi = d[2].split(",");
multi[0];
multi[1];
multi[2]; etc....

Comment: no se entiende bien tu codigo, yo intente hacer esto: $.each(d[2].split(","), function(i,e){

                $("#tecnologia").multiselect("refresh");
            });                                                                                                                               pero no resulto

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te indica Bryro es correcto pero tu no haces ninguna asignación, debería ser algo así:

```
        $.each(d[2].split(","), function(i,e){
            $('#tecnologia option[value="'+e+'"]').prop('checked', true);
        });
```

En el bucle each es donde debes poner el `checked` a las opciones correspondientes.

Personalmente yo usaría indices numéricos, hacer operaciones con literales de texto es poco flexible  (mayúsculas y espacios son un dolor de cabeza, errores ortográficos, idiomas.... ) y el JSON resultante es más reducido.

Algo como:

```
 <select class="test_3" id="tecnologia" name="tecnologia[]" multiple="multiple" style="height:10px;">
    <option id="tec_1" value="1">Algebra</option> 
    <option id="tec_2" value="2">Aritmetica</option> 
    <option id="tec_3" value="3">Lenguaje</option> 
    <option id="tec_4" value="4">Literatura</option>
    <option id="tec_5" value="5">Historia Universal</option> 
    <option id="tec_6" value="6">Biologia</option>
    <option id="tec_7" value="7">Quimica</option>
    <option id="tec_8" value="8">Fisica</option>
 </select>
```

y el bucle que actualiza sería:

```
        $.each(d[2].split(","), function(i,e){
            $('#tec_'+e).prop('checked', true);
        })
```

Informacion adicional sobre el check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery